# What advantages does CPLD have w.r.t microcontrollers in driving MOSFET drivers in inverter?

Tags: microcontroller, inverter, mosfet-driver

I have seen some designs where CPLDs have been used in driving the MOSFET driver in an inverter circuit. What advantage does is provide with regards to driving the same using controllers like TI piccolo c2000 series?

Note: I’ve never used CPLDs and consider my self as a newbie in that area. Would like to hear some conceptual understanding or suggestions for reading on the same.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Determinism.  Exact same timings, every time, all the time. More immediate reactions to events as well with no time variability.

Comment: @DKNguyen  could you provide or suggest some design docs or  reading on it for better understanding?

Comment: Not really. It's just one of those things where either part can do the job. You might find more material on FPGAs instead of CPLDs.

Comment: Okay thank you :) I’ll look up on those.

Comment: It's also easier to replace a CPLD than an MCU if it goes obsolete, especially between brands since the "code" is far more universal and pin assignments are far more flexible.

Comment: @Dknguyen that do makes sense in the way of economics.Thank you and I’ve to read up for fpgas articles for better understanding.

Comment: @DKNguyen, you should post your answers as answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Determinism. Exact same timings, every time, all the time. More immediate, potentially simultaneous, reactions to events with much, much less time variability. Always the same number of clock cycles if you are using a clock.

It's also easier to replace a CPLD than an MCU if it goes obsolete, especially between brands since the "code" is far more universal and pin assignments are far more flexible. Good for products where you plan on manufacturing them for decades.

Comment: With very little time variability, rather than "no time variability". The delays vary minutely with temperature and between parts. Best to send the message that every engineering characteristic has a tolerance.